# Why is the column name from a CSV file different than its DataTable?

Tags: ado.net, csv

I'm using an OleDbConnection, OleDbCommand, and OleDbDataReader to read a CSV file into a DataTable.

The CSV file uses the first row as a header row.

Some of the names in the header have non alphanumeric characters like ( _ . / ).

When the system creates the Column names it is transposing the . (period) character into a # (pound sign).

Why is this one character being changed and is there a way to stop the change, making the . (period) stay in the column name?

Thank you,
Keith

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's replacing periods because they're metacharacters in SQL for specifying hierarchies.  I don't believe it's at all advisable to try to preserve the period.

Comment: So, would you advise sourceColumnName.Replace(".", "#"); instead of trying to preserve the period?

Comment: I'm unclear on why you would do that; isn't OLE doing it for you already?

Comment: Here is an example: object data = datatable.Rows[rowIndex][sourceColumnName.Replace(".", "#")];